# What is a SIG_0 when looking at an strace

Tags: linux, c++, strace

Attaching strace to a process that is using a lot of cpu, shows that the pid is 'killed' over and over.

The process is using 130% cpu. What is a tgkill( SIG_0) ?

```
strace -p 3876 

nanosleep({0, 100000}, NULL) = 0 
tgkill(3876, 3884, SIG_0) = 0 
tgkill(3876, 3885, SIG_0) = 0 ...repeats over and over.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`man tgkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/tgkill):

> tgkill() sends the signal sig to the thread with the thread ID tid in the thread group tgid. (By contrast, kill(2) can only be used to send a signal to a process (i.e., thread group) as a whole, and the signal will be delivered to an arbitrary thread within that process.)

Which just leaves us the question of what signal 0 represents. [The answer is, none at all](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/monitoring-processes-kill-0):

> If you have a process ID but aren't sure whether it's valid, you can use the most unlikely of candidates to test it: the kill command. If you don't see any reference to this on the kill(1) man page, check the info pages. The man/info page states that signal 0 is special and that the exit code from kill tells whether a signal could be sent to the specified process (or processes).

The `tgkill` calls, then, are testing for the existence of various threads within whatever process you're monitoring via `strace`. The return value of 0 indicates that the threads so tested do exist; the question to answer now is, why is the process looping over the test? (I assume that's what it's doing, at any rate; presumably if it ever did anything else that you saw, you'd have mentioned it in your question.)